# Detect angle of a black & white halftone screen

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing

Having a 1-bit black & white halftone image as input, I need to extract the angle used for positioning the dots, as shown in the example below:

[image: Halftone screen with detected images]

My intented approach is to identify all isolated areas below a certain threshold (I can assume all dots are in a 20x20 area) and make a list of all center points of these dots. The second step is to run a Hough transform on these specific points to find the interesting angles. The main problem is that this seems to generate quite a lot of points, making the Hough transform (i) slow and (ii) giving false positives, which need filtering out in turn.

I can't help but have the feeling that I am overcomplicating things and I am overlooking a simple elegant solution to this problem. Any ideas or approaches that I may have overlooked?

Comment: Simple idea: get coordinates of centers of all small black and white circles.

Comment: Interesting problem - try Googling "de-screening algorithm". This method looks interesting http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDMQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F221210386_A_New_Descreening_Technique_in_the_Frequency_Domain%2Ffile%2Fd912f50b8ffe13ccc7.pdf&ei=YACgU9XPDMfQ7Aa734DYCw&usg=AFQjCNHDt8xJI7oI2X2BtO_pPOBS0Un1MQ&sig2=SRdn1lJFEcVcoIRKOBUSgQ&bvm=bv.68911936,d.ZGU

Comment: I will look into these publications. Most seem to rely heavy on filtering though, with no consideration for the angle of the dots.

Comment: Just a small nag: The image above is not a 1-bit BW image but a downsampled grayscale image with some lines drawn on it.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited it in photoshop to add the lines to it and downscaled it a bit to show my intented question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FFT**

Try to run a Fourier transform for the image. The screen will produce very sharp frequency peaks. With those peaks you will get the screen frequency and angle quite accurately even from a noisy image.

I just transformed your image back to a grayscale image:

[image: Grayscale image with screen dots]

Then I run a 2D fft over it:

[image: FFT power spectrum of the image above]

The bright dots at (20,27) and its mirror positions are very strong peaks, orders of magnitude stronger than anything else in the image. This curve shows the power spectrum over row 20:

[image]

So the screen frequency in the y direction is approximately 193/20 = 9.7 pixels (image height 193), and in the x direction 263/27 = 9.7 pixels. This is the inter-dot distance in each direction, and a bit of trigonometry is usually needed to calculate the axes. The peak position can be interpolated more accurately from the Fourier power spectrum by using the area around the peaks, if needed. The peaks can also be folded on top of each other to reduce noise.

**Performance?**

FFT is a rather quick transform to calculate (at least compared to Hough & al.), but with large images it takes a lot of space and time. You may use it on several smallish areas (e.g. 10 dots across), which also helps you in case the screen is not even. At least in that case it will be fast. On my computer it takes 418 us to run a 128x128 pixel 2D FFT.

**Notes on FFT**

Readers not familiar with the Fourier transform should be aware of the fact that I have used some sloppy language above and in the comments. The transform itself is "Fourier transform", FFT is just one algorithm (*de facto* standard in image processing) to perform a discrete Fourier transform (DFT).

One thing that tends to confuse people when calculating FFTs and comparing the results to literature is the position of the zero frequency in the image. In most textbooks the zero frequency (actually the sum of the image pixel values) is in the center of the image. Most FFT libraries put the zero frequency to the upper left hand corner (as in my example).

So, in the textbooks zero frequency components are usually close to the centre of the transformed image. With most FFT libraries low frequencies are close to each corner of the image. (There are usually functions with names like `fftshift`to transform between these two representations.)

FT is a complex transformation. If a real-valued signal (such as a single image) is transformed, there will be a lot of symmetry in the resulting transformed image. This is usually not very important, but sometimes it can be used to speed things up or save some memory.

Complexity of single-dimensional FFT is O(n log n). In the two-dimensional case the FFT is first run for each column, and then each row and is thus O(x y log y + y x log x) = O(x y (log x + log y)) or O(n^2 log n) for a square image. Modern computers are very fast with FFTs (and can be boosted even further by using the GPUs), but large FFTs with thousands of points to each direction are a warning sign of one using the wrong algorithm.

Comment: I am a total novice at Fourier Transformations, hence why I hadn't considered it yet, but I will definitely investigate this further and do some implementations. Deducing the actual frequency and angle from the x and y frequencies should be trivial. Thanks a lot for this information!

Comment: You should rotate and skew your image to see how the FFT peaks behave. It is quite simple in practice, but hard to explain. If you want to interpolate the frequency peaks, the peaks can be approximated by parabola in the log of the power spectrum. (Beware, don't try to find a mathematical justification to that one, it just works...) If you need a fft library, fftw is the most common one.

Comment: @DrV This is a really good answer, do you mind if I ask you if there is a reference or a book where I can learn more about how to use FFTs and the applications to images?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Thank you. My suggestion is that you start with a search engine using words "fourier transform image processing". There are more and less mathematical explanations for you to choose depending on how comfortable you are with maths. It might help if you first try to learn the 1-d fourier transform if you are not familiar with it. And get a hold of Matlab, Pylab, or something equivalent so that you can experiment easily. I'll also add some further comments about FFT into my answer.

Comment: @DrV Thanks for your response.  I'm slightly familiar with FFT on a superficial level (in fact I've even implemented the nlogn algorithm for it), but I wanted to understand it properly on a more fundamental level.  Do you think learning from the web would suffice or do you perhaps know a book that I could read?  e.g. Should I start with a book on signal processing or should I go straight for image processing?

Comment: I finished a first implementation and it works like a charm :) For determining the exact peak I create the parabol over the highest point in the power curve and it's direct neighbours only. This gives a better approximation, though not 100% exact. Adding in more neighbours makes it impossible to find a good fit.

Comment: @oddstar: Nice to hear it works! Instead of taking the parabola (in 2d) over the peak of the power spectrum, use the log of the power spectrum. For some reason it usually gives very good results. (It is theoretically correct when the signal has a gaussian window but works with other window functions and even without any windowing.) You are on the right track when you use only 3x3 points (or even only 4 direct neighbours plus the maximum).

Comment: @CaptainCodeman As you know the basics and have the basic understanding, you are probably best off in the web. There are a lot of good and a lot of bad examples, you'll learn form both. Pay attention to windowing functions, that is usually not too well covered in the examples. Also, if you have an irregular grid in your image, FT is not a good tool. Most FT applications in image processing are simple convolution filters, image analysis (as in this question) is not that often performed. For fundamental understanding, be sure to understand the 1D version first.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, I actually didn't try it:

- Run an erosion until you are left with 1 pixel per blob of points
- connect each point with the nearest one with a line (I mean, just memorize the parameters for the line, don't draw it)
- after you connect few points (is up to you to find the optimal number) you should be able to average the angle of the lines that connect the points

Comment: Looking into the idea of erosion, this should also be able to isolate dots that have grown attached to their neighbours, which would solve quite a bit. Will do some experiments and report back.